# How might one "short out" a diode?

Tags: diodes, failure

Many moons ago, as a kid, I was playing around with electronics and proudly demonstrated my latest project to my parents. In my eagerness, I made a mistake in my nest of wires, and the acrid pale grey smoke of shame was released from a small silicon signal diode, perhaps a 1N4148.

My father stated that I probably "shorted out the diode". I bowed to his superior knowledge without question, and sheepishly requested that he replace the diode (I had not yet mastered the soldering iron).

Now I have age and rebellion flowing through my veins, and I demand an explanation! What might cause such an embarrassing failure?

Comment: To "short out" a component is to connect a conductor between its terminals, so that it is effectively removed from the circuit. Shorted out passive components cannot be damaged, but there can be some domino effect that causes trouble elsewhere. (Shorting out a voltage source is a different story: that is a short circuit.) You may have shorted out whatever was supposed to limit current to the diode, effectively using the diode to short out a voltage source.

Comment: +1 for some of the most evocative language I've ever seen on this site.

Comment: @angelatlarge Alas, my faux-eloquence is largely sententious! (I'm in a strange mood today, as you might have gathered)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Shorting out" something is layperson's description of a large number of electrical/electronics failures. It rarely is accurate.

What more likely happened is that you did not have a current limiting resistor or there was one but its value was too small and as a result, too much current went through the diode and turned it into a very short-lived LED.

Comment: So, the lifetime of the LED was "shorte(ne)d" out. :)

Comment: The answer seems to be right, except nowhere did the OP mention a _LED_.  The part that what "shorted" was a "small silicon signal diode, perhaps a 1N4148"

Comment: I believe by "short-lived LED" he meant that the diode in question glowed (emitted light) for a split second when it failed. It was a bit of a joke.

Comment: This seems likely. The candle that burns several orders of magnitude brighter, lives several orders of magnitude shorter. *Requiescat in pace*, my silicon friend!